# Bibliography, and how to use it

Tags: bibliographies

I'm trying to use a very rudimentary bibliography, with the alpha style...

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{bm}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{enumitem}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{thebibliography}{99}


    \bibitem*{[Cho07]}
    Cho, J. S. and White, H. (2007), Testing for Regime Switching.   
    Econometrica, 75: 1671–1720. doi: 10.1111/j.1468-0262.2007.00809.x

    \end{thebibliography}
    \end{document}
```

After compiling I get something like:

> [1] [Cho07]Cho, J. S. and White, H. (2007), Testing for Regime Switching. Econometrica, 75: 1671–1720. doi: 10.1111/j.1468-0262.2007.00809.x

When I would like to have something like:

> [Cho07]Cho, J. S. and White, H. (2007), Testing for Regime Switching. Econometrica, 75: 1671–1720. doi: 10.1111/j.1468-0262.2007.00809.x

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please note that is possible to do the references by hand, and certain situations require it; but most people are too lazy for that and use tools for auto generation. Put the different elements in a very simple database and use `biblatex` along with an auxiliary program called `biber`. You can change the style and other stuff very easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. Instead of

```
\bibitem*{[Cho07]}
Cho, J. S. and White, H. (2007), Testing for Regime Switching. 
Econometrica, 75: 1671–1720. doi: 10.1111/j.1468-0262.2007.00809.x
```

you need to write

```
\bibitem[Cho07]{Cho07}
Cho, J. S. and White, H. (2007), Testing for Regime Switching. 
Econometrica, 75: 1671--1720. doi: 10.1111/j.1468-0262.2007.00809.x
```

---

The output of a full MWE -- note that also suggest you encase the doi string in a `\url` directive, in part to allow automatic line-breaking (if needed):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
%%\usepackage{amsmath} % is loaded automatically by 'mathtools'
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{99} 
\bibitem[Cho07]{Cho07}
Cho, J. S. and White, H. (2007), 
Testing for Regime Switching. 
Econometrica, 75: 1671--1720. 
doi: \url{10.1111/j.1468-0262.2007.00809.x}

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks! It really solved my problem, and another one I was also having. ;)